# rails not registering javascript files under app/assets/javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to integrate d3 with my rails app. After installing the `d3-rails` gem, I came across [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) on d3. Somewhere in the tutorial, the below code is provided

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}

</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script>

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
```

If I were to include the above code as it is into my *new.html.erb* file, the chart will show.

I then created a new *graph.js* fiel under *app/assets/javascripts* and decided to put everything between the `<script>` `</script`> tag inside *graph.js*. Now when I open up *new.html.erb*, the chart will not show anymore.

Am I doing something wrong here that's causing rails to not recognize *graph.js* ?

Comment: I think you should do two things: open the source code of the page, look into `/scripts/application.js` and examine if `d3` code has been included. Second thing is to open the developer console of the browser and examine for potential exceptions with JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile the assets?

You'll need to run:

```
rake asset:precompile
```

Comment: rails is giving a `Don't know how to build task 'asset:precompile'` error. Not exactly sure what it means

Comment: I think it's suppose to be `rake assets:precompile` , but I tried that and it still does not resolve my problem.