# Rails 4: "//= require_tree ." in application.js doesn't include my js file in /app/assets/javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to follow a [tutorial](http://www.overfitted.com/blog/?p=302) on adding d3.js graph to Rails 4 application. The example application is on [github](https://github.com/qwwqwwq/rails_d3_seed) and works as expected.

My problem is that when I try to replicate this application from scratch or add this graph to my existing project the js file in `/app/assets/javascripts` is not included in resources for some reason despite the fact that the `//= require_tree .` line is present in `/app/assets/javascripts/applications.js` files.

I can see this as the only problem since if I paste the code from problematic file into the console, it works.

I found similar questions and followed advice given but couldn't fix my problem.

I've already tried `rake assets:precompile` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859409/rails-not-registering-javascript-files-under-app-assets-javascripts)

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you have a coffee file in /app/assets/javascripts with the same name?

Comment: Yes I do, nothing in it apart from few commented out lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had file.coffee and I created file.js which was not added. When I renamed file.coffee to file.js everything was fine. However, you could just use www.js2.coffee to convert your js code to coffee and then use the file.coffee file instead.

Comment: First of all THANKS SO MUCH, I was scratching my head not this for a while. It is weird though, the original project from the tutorial has the coffee file and it works. I guess my issue may return at some point if I decide to use coffee script after all.

Comment: OK, I guess this is just something I had to learn the hard way. Not sure why both js and coffee files were in the example project (or why it actually works) but according to [asset pipeline docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) it it should be one or the other, or file.js.coffee if I wan to parse it with coffee first an then javascript. At least that's how I understand this.